# Data migration: copy data with insert select and fill unique column

Tags: postgresql, schema-migration

I have some tables in Postgres like this.

```
create table foo (
    txt text
);
insert into foo (txt) values ('a');
insert into foo (txt) values ('b');
insert into foo (txt) values ('c');

create table bar (
  txt text,
  n integer not null unique
);
```

I'm doing a schema migration. I would like to migrate data from `foo` to `bar`. I'd like `bar` to look like this.

```
=# select * from new;
txt | n
----+--
a   | 1
b   | 2
c   | 3
```

`n` doesn't have to be sequential, but it does have to be `unique` and `not null`.

I thought this query would work.

```
insert into bar (txt, n)
select txt, generate_series(1, (select count(*) from foo))
from foo;
```

But I think that's generating rows 1-N over and over again for each `'a', 'b', 'c'`, which violates the `unique` constraint.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/06e92c

---

*Update*

Okay, I found one hacky way to do it.

```
insert into bar (txt, n)
select txt, trunc(random() * 999999 + 1)
from foo;
```

Of course this isn't guaranteed to be `unique`. :/ But, if the data set is small enough, you might be able to scrape by with this.

Also, I understand why the first approach failed now. `generate_series` returns multiple rows, whereas with `random` I only return 1 row.

Comment: *n doesn't have to be sequential* Refine: "doesn't have to be sequential" or "must be non-sequental"?

Comment: It can be sequential or not. The important detail is that the values are unique.

Comment: If so I cannot understand why you try to set `stop` parameter for `generate_series`...

Comment: I was trying to generate a series from 1 to 3. I was hoping that would make n = 1, 2, 3 during the insert.

Comment: *I was trying to generate a series from 1 to 3.* Generate from 1 to "as it turns out"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `row_number()`

```
insert into bar (txt, n)
select txt, row_number() over ()
from foo;
```

I left out an `order by` which would slow down the query and wouldn't really be an advantage in your case as you just want a unique number.

An alternative would be to create a sequence for it, if the performance of the window function isn't sufficient.

```
create sequence seq_foo_nr;

insert into bar (txt, n)
select txt, nextval('seq_foo_nr')
from foo;

drop sequence seq_foo_nr;
```

If you need an auto-generated number anyway, then define `nr` as an identity column:

```
create table bar (
  txt text,
  n integer not null unique generated always as identity
);

insert into bar (txt)
select txt
from foo;
```